# SVG file is not showing in Chrome browser

Tags: html, svg, vector-graphics

I don't Know much about SVG stuff and recently I come up with this problem
the SVG files are showing when we paste its code in the HTML file
I have seen many youtube videos in which they use `<img>` tag to emmet the SVG file in the browser
but I don't know is browser a problem for this or not but when I try to emmet the SVG file using `<img>`
tag I just don't show up on the page but works when pastes its code.

Can anyone tell me ho can I emmet the SVG file to my chrome browser using `<img>` or any other way but not pasting the whole SVG code in the HTML file because it is annoying and also not looks pretty good.

Edit:-

currently, I am making a navbar model which is in the left-hand side
I referred to [this video](https://youtu.be/biOMz4puGt8) I know it this video he used full SVG code to emmet the SVG image but in normal I searched for inserting the SVG image in those tutorials they used `<img>` and I also want to use `<img>` tag because without that I have to pass whole tons of lines of code which is very difficult to handle
my navbar is like this:-

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-items">

<a href="#" class="nav-link">
<svg> Here I want to use img tag instead of the whole svg code</svg>

<span>Name of SVG</span>
                </a>
</li>
</ul>
    </nav>
```

i just want to use `<img>` tag to insert the svg image , not writhing the svg code and that's what I am unable to do.

Comment: Can you share the svg code ? it is most likely the issue.
Also try to set a width and height to your image

Comment: Thanx for that I will edit my question for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an svg in an `<img>` tag, use the src attribute with the path of your svg.

Example:

```html
<img src="/path/to/svg.svg">
```

That should display your svg in your browser.

An alternative to that is just to use an `<svg>` tag in your HTML.
Example:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_myfirst) is a link to a w3schools tutorial that might help.

Comment: Soo Sorry to wast all of your precious time for my stupidity it reason it was not working is that I pasted the SVG file outside my project folder and gave the wrong path for it.        Really Sorry for this